# Squared Field Derivative Model of Eddy Current Losses in Inductor

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electromagnetic-induction

For a project that I am working on I would like to calculate the expected eddy current losses that occur in a rod shaped inductor. In order to do so I was referring to [the following paper](https://engineering.dartmouth.edu/inductor/papers/sfdj.pdf). The paper uses a method referred to as SFD ("Squared-Field-Derivative") to calculate the losses.

The paper starts by explaining that the instantaneous power dissipation of a cylindrical piece of wire of length $l$, diameter $d_{c}$ and resistivity $\rho_{c}$ in an external, oscillating magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$ of frequency $\omega$ is given by:

$$P(t)=\frac{\pi l d_{c}^4}{64 \rho_{c}}\left(\frac{dB}{dt}\right)^2 \sim \omega^2 \tag{1}$$

It then goes on to show that the eddy current losses in a two winding transformer with oscillatory currents $i_{1}$ and $i_{2}$ is given by (7):

$$ P_{e,total} = [\frac{di_{1}}{dt},\frac{di_{2}}{dt}]\mathbf{D}[\frac{di_{1}}{dt},\frac{di_{2}}{dt}]^T\sim\omega^2 \tag{2}$$

where $\mathbf{D}$ is a constant matrix.

From these equations, I would expect that the resistance $R(w)$ of a single coil would start growing proportional to $\omega^2$ as the frequency is increased. If a unit current $\hat{i}=1$ is applied to the inductor one should have:

$$P(\omega) = \frac{1}{2}R(\omega) \hat{i}^2 = \frac{1}{2} R(\omega) \sim \omega^2$$.

However, when I actually built my inductor I  measured that $R(\omega)\sim\omega^{1.68}$. The blue line shows the measured real part of he inductor impedance $R_{meas}=Re\{Z(j\omega)\}$ compared to a power law $\sim \omega^{1.68}$:

[image: Real Part of Impedance of Coil (Measured)]

In the paper, the following test results are given and compared to calculations:

[image: Resistance Prediction and Measurement according to 1]

I loaded this plot in a plot digitizer and measured the slope of the curves in the double logarithmic plot to get the exponent of the power law in the frequency range where the resistance starts increasing. I also measured $\omega\sim f^{1.68}$.

So I don't understand why the AC resistance grows proportional to $\omega^{1.68}$ and not $\omega^2$? Wouldn't (1) and (2) imply that $R(\omega)\sim\omega^2$?

Comment: Your link to the paper just goes to the first figure in your question

Comment: Hello and thanks for your comment, I adjusted the link.